# emacs function to uncomment regardless of mode

Tags: emacs, comments, equals, region

Main goal: making a smart "uncomment" function suitable for any mode.

```
(defun uncomment-mode-specific ()
  (interactive)
  (if (region-active-p)
      (comment-region (region-beginning) (region-end) -1)  ; so far so good
    (if (= ";" (line-beginning-position))                   ; here is the problem
         (message "successful")
       (message "unsuccessful"))
))
```

In the `if` statement, I would like to check for the value of the first character of the line, and if it `equals` the variable `comment-start` (which would return "`;`" in emacs lisp), goto `beginning-of-line` and delete the character. Ideas?

**EDIT:** More clarification as requested in a comment below follows. I would like a function to do:

1) If a region is selected, remove the comments (here that uncomment-region or comment-dwim would work as pointed out by Patrick)

ELSE:

2) If the first character of the line at point is a comment character, remove the comment character.

ELSE:

3) Search current line for comment (excluding `\%` or `\;`, mode dependent), move up to comment and kill the line starting with the comment sign.

I could not see how you would want this to work differently. It could then be bound to one key to simply remove comments, depending on the mode, using `comment-start` to identify the comment character.

Comment: what's wrong with `M-x uncomment-region`?

Comment: I kind of want a bit of modded behavior. But I think it's a good place to start. What it is missing is an "if" in the case of a comment ";" being on the line, i would prefer it to kill the part after the ;.

Comment: I believe it should be in this order: 1) if a region is selected, then this would indeed work. If nothing is selected then 2) check whether character at beginning of line = comment character (if yes, remove). 3) if nothing selected, and no comment at beginning of line, incremental search to comment character, and then kill-line on it. This would seem the best type of functioning.

Comment: Now stuck at incremental search :(

Comment: Also check out the `C-h f comment-dwim`, you need to have a region specified for that command, but you can check out the file newcomment.el where the function is defined to see how it works at least.

Comment: @Patrick Please post your comment as an answer, it's probably what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Please explain more precisely what you want.  E.g. show the text before and the text after.  I have the impression that what you want might be closer to what we call "kill-comment" (i.e. don't just remove the comment markers, but remove the comment altogether).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm posting this as an alternative answer, since what you are trying to do is partly done already with the `comment-dwim` command. From the docs (you can find it using `C-h f comment-dwim`)

> comment-dwim is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
>   `newcomment.el'.
>
> It is bound to `M-;`.
>
> (comment-dwim *ARG*)
>
> Call the comment command you want (Do What I Mean).
>   If the region is active and `transient-mark-mode` is on, call
>     `comment-region` (unless it only consists of comments, in which
>     case it calls `uncomment-region`).
>   Else, if the current line is empty, call `comment-insert-comment-function`
>   if it is defined, otherwise insert a comment and indent it.
>   Else if a prefix *ARG* is specified, call `comment-kill`.
>   Else, call `comment-indent`.
>   You can configure `comment-style` to change the way regions are commented.

So in order to use it, simply select a region with `C-SPC` (set-mark-command) and move the caret to the other point and run `comment-dwim`.

Comment: +1, though it's not exactly the answer. My code already takes care appropriately for "region". My question is more to deal with the other situations.